# How to sync files between 2 servers on the internet?

Tags: windows, sync, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

We are trying sync files between 2 Windows servers.  These servers are not on the same network.  A process on server 1 generates the file.  A process on server 2 needs to consume the file.

At first I was thinking that the process on server 1 would FTP or HTTP the file to server 2, but the powers that be won't let me setup a web/ftp server, nor will they punch a hold in the redirect table.

Then, I thought DropBox, but it seems to require that a user be logged in (I might be wrong here) to work.  So that is out.

What are some of the other ways to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you can setup ftp on both servers, you can use [AutoFileMove](http://www.autofilemove.com/) to sync the 2 servers and transfer files from/to any of servers, and also you can do the same with dropbox or amazon s3